# Change the input language of the textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i select Arabic then text box will acccept input from me as a arabic. I mean to say that when i select a language from a dropdown then according to that language my keyboard layout is change according to selected Language.

Comment: Don't delete [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34806272/1324033) just to remake it, *edit* it to address the comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set textbox font as Arabic through css.
As 'font-family: Arabic Transparent;' and 'text-align: right;'

OR

You need to set then text box lang attribute using javascript depending upon selected language in dropdown.

$("#textBox").attr("lang", "en"); English
$("#textBox").attr("lang", "fa-IR"); Persian etc.

Comment: what if i need farsi ?